# Stored procedure Call Text for procedure with in and out params

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter, informatica-cloud

I have stored procedure with  params as below : which I have to call before source reads

```
PROCEDURE xxx(table_name IN VARCHAR2,
              where_clause IN VARCHAR2,
              interval IN NUMBER,
              hint IN VARCHAR2,
              rows_processed OUT NUMBER,
              db_name OUT VARCHAR2,
              owner OUT VARCHAR2,
              start_time OUT DATE,
              end_time OUT DATE)
```

I would like to know what would be call text for calling above procedure ? am passing in params as mapping parameters from file ,

can we do in unconnected ?or connected procedure?

Answer (score 0):

Mappings do not call stored procedures. You will want a pre-processing script in your Mapping Configuration Task that calls the stored procedure before the mapping itself runs if the stored procedure is preparing the data in the table. If you need the output from the stored procedure, put a service call in front of it and use the service as your source.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure [load order](http://exploreinformatica.com/informatica-target-load-plan/) in your mapping and have two data streams which run sequentially.  First, you'll run the stream with the sp. It'll get the params from whatever source you need and just link it into the sp transform and into some target.  It may be as simple as this:

src --> sq --> sp --> tgt

Then second you can run the rest of your mapping which is dependent on the result of the sp.

Alternatively, you could also create a separate mapping and session to just call the sp transform.

But given that you must execute this before the second source reads, you cannot use an unconnected sp transform as you will not be able to get the output from it.